# Format given string value using string format

Tags: java

I have the string format like S PCF=$S($L(VAL)=5:$E(VAL,1,2)*" "*$E(VAL,3,5),$L(VAL)=6:$E(VAL,1,3)*" "*$E(VAL,4,6),1:$E(VAL,1,4)*" "*$E(VAL,5,7)).

I want to format the value in above format. What is best i can do.  In format  5:$E(VAL,1,2)*" "*$E(VAL,3,5)..
Here 5 means if string contains 5 characters.then need space after 2 characters.
Ex: if value is 12345 then i need to display 12 345.

Thank you very much for your response.

Is there any way i can match any regular expression or any with 
S PCF=$S($L(VAL)=5:$E(VAL,1,2)*" "*$E(VAL,3,5),$L(VAL)=6:$E(VAL,1,3)*" "*$E(VAL,4,6),1:$E(VAL,1,4)*" "*$E(VAL,5,7)).

to find the values here? In this :

```
5:$E(VAL,1,2)_" "_$E(VAL,3,5)
```

i need to get Lenght of String is : 5
                   indexes 1,2,3,5
                   and separator is " "(Space)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the first part, but have a look at the Formatter api, it includes at lot of examples: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: Formatter string: $E(VAL,1,2)" "$E(VAL,3,5)
 The meaning of this is i need to keep space after 2 nd character. Ex: Val is 12345 then i need to display 12 345.

Comment: The NumberFormat class might be of use for you: int number = 12345; NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("sv")); System.out.println(nf.format(number)); The default format for the swedish locale is to use space as separator for numbers like 1000 -> 1 000. Try with your Locale, or without setting the Locale at all, and check the result